# Increasing RAM beyond system specifications

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, upgrade, lenovo-laptop

I have had my laptop (Lenovo z570) for a couple of years now, and I am in the mood to do a bit of system upgrading. I checked the documentation online, and it has always said that it can handle up to 8GB of RAM. Yesterday, I had the opportunity to test a pair of 8GB sticks in the laptop, and it worked fine. I didn't have the chance to test it fully, but all 16GB was available, and I performed a few benchmark tests on it which gave me a much higher system score.

But, even though the system states that has a max of 8GB of RAM, and 16GB works fine, is there anything I should be aware of before going out and buying some new sticks?

Comment: BTW, does the documentation say 8GB *per slot*, by chance?

Comment: Nope, system max: 8GB

Comment: Interesting... How do you know it *worked* fine (your post seems to be about detection only)? Did you run a program which used more than 8 GB RAM?

Comment: I am unsure, I launched every program I had, several instances of Eclipse, C4D, Word, Outlook, and that all started. I also discovered that the spec says the max ram speed it supports is 1333MHz, but the RAM I was testing was 1600MHz, and the Benchmark results verified that it was operating at that (1600) frequency

Comment: The specific CPU and chipset used by the system would be required to answer this question. [Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/53438/intel-core-i3-2350m-processor-3m-cache-2_30-ghz) says it supports 16GB.

Comment: @Ramhound that seems to make sense. All the spec sheets I have looked at claim that it can only have an i3 or i5, but I am using an i7-2670QM

Comment: @cgoddard - I cannot provide an answer because the answer would basically involve me providing information that already exists on Intel's website.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, but you found it. Anyway, thats never stopped the rest of the stack exchange network being essentially a repository of wikipedia

Comment: @cgoddard - I hold myself to a higher level of quality.  If an answer involves linking to a product specification it doesn't really make a great answer.  Even if I were to pull the information from the page, its still only listing known product specifications.  You can answer your own question if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good chance that in 2010/11 when the notebook was created, that although all the underlying tech was in place, 8GB sticks didn't exist on the market yet and so they could not be tested, approved or documented by Lenovo.

IE:

- [Crucial today introduced Crucial 8GB DDR3-1333MHz UDIMM (desktop) and SODIMM (laptop) memory modules...](http://www.legitreviews.com/new-crucial-8gb-ddr3-memory-modules-announced_11329) - Aug. 2011.
- [Corsair Announces 8GB DDR3 Memory Modules](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/DDR3-Vengeance-Value-Select-8GB-Intel-core,13607.html) - Oct. 2011.

Since they couldn't test them, they won't say they'll work and won't support that configuration, even if they do actually work.  Nor will they go back and test/approve them with a previous model.

If they seem to work, and you can run Memtest86+ against them for 72 hours error free, then I'd say you're good to go.

Comment: Well, according to CPU-Z, the chips were made manufactured in the 46th week of 2011, and I got the laptop in Jan 2012, so it is likely that they hadn't tested it then, cheers. I will definitely be dismanteling it tonight and re-testing all the RAM again